# What type of view controller is used for this app?

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, swift

[image]

Does anybody know what kind of view controller this app uses? I am trying to implement one somewhat like this but can not get the tab bar to appear at the bottom when I use the table view controller. I also can not get the title of the view to appear at the top where it says home.

Comment: At first view (sic!) this is a normal tableview, the one at the bottom is just another view on top, placed at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is a tab bar controller. The home tab you show may just have a navigation bar placed on top of it as a sub view or it is embedded into a navigation controller.

[image: Image of solution]

My image shows a tab bar controller as the root controller and initial controller and the view from the first tab embedded in a navigation controller.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The screen you are looking at is a combination of a UItabBarController a UINavigationController and a UITableViewController.